# Extract data from salesforce/exacttarget views using talend

Tags: marketing-cloud, amazon-s3, talend

I would like to know if it is possible to migrate data from a ExactTarget/Salesforce view directly to an Amazon s3 bucket, without having to create a DataExtension, using an ETL tool like Talend. If yes, could you please guide me as to how it can be done.

Comment: What "view" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You have two mediums for extracting data from Marketing Cloud: flat file or SOAP API.

If you're looking for activity data via file, you can use the poorly documented [**Tracking Extracts**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/). This is recommended for large data sets.  If you're wanting to write this data to AWS, you'll need some process to consume the files and insert the rows.

You can retrieve tracking event data via SOAP API, but only 2500 rows at a time. Those objects are outlined [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm).